# Como insertar informacion en celdas especificas en un archivo de excel usando C#

Tags: c#, excel

buen dia. Tengo una hoja de en Excel que voy a usar como una plantilla. Alguien tiene un ejemplo de como poder insertar informacion en celdas especificas para ese archivo de Excel??

Tengo esta funcion pero esta en el lenguaje de Visual Basic .Net, pero no he podido realizar la misma funcion en C#

```
Public Sub FacturaExcel()
    'El siguiente codigo es para crear la ruta,entre comillas se pone la ruta donde esta el libro
    Dim Ruta As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.xls")

    strRutaExcel = Ruta

    'El siguiente codigo es para abrir el libro y hacerlo visible, si se quiere dejar el libro oculto, se cambia la palabra True por False
    xlibro = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlibro.Workbooks.Open(strRutaExcel)
    xlibro.Visible = True

    xlibro.Sheets("Factura").Select() 'Nombre del libro

    'esta es la instruccion para modificar la celda con el contenido de un textbox llamado textbox1, ustedes le pueden poner el nombre que deseen al textbox
    xlibro.Range("B4").Value = txtCliente.Text

    ''Cargamos las celdas con los datos de la base de datos
    Dim Conexion As Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    Dim Adaptador As Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter

    Conexion = New Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    Conexion.ConnectionString = "Data Source=abarrotes.db3;Version=3;"

    Conexion.Open()

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Adaptador = New Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from productos", Conexion)
    Adaptador.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim fila As DataRow
        Dim ValorInicial As Integer = 7 ''Celda donde empezamos a insertar los articulos
        Dim Total As Double = 0

        For Each fila In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            xlibro.Range("A" & ValorInicial).Value = fila("Descripcion")
            xlibro.Range("B" & ValorInicial).Value = fila("precio")
            xlibro.Range("C" & ValorInicial).Value = fila("Cantidad")
            xlibro.Range("D" & ValorInicial).Value = fila("cantidad") * fila("precio")
            Total = Total + (fila("cantidad") * fila("precio"))

            ValorInicial += 1

        Next

        xlibro.Range("D17").Value = Total
    End If

    Conexion.Close()
End Sub
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Tanto VB.Net cómo C#.Net son transpilables entre sí, por lo que puedes usar alguna herramienta de transformación de código cómo esta https://converter.telerik.com para convertir de VB.Net a C# o viceversa.

Si te funciona ese código en VB.Net, esta versión en C# debería servir:

```
public void FacturaExcel() {
    // El siguiente codigo es para crear la ruta,entre comillas se pone la ruta donde esta el libro
    string Ruta = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.xls");

    strRutaExcel = Ruta;

    // El siguiente codigo es para abrir el libro y hacerlo visible, si se quiere dejar el libro oculto, se cambia la palabra True por False
    xlibro = Interaction.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
    xlibro.Workbooks.Open(strRutaExcel);
    xlibro.Visible = true;

    xlibro.Sheets("Factura").Select(); // Nombre del libro

    // esta es la instruccion para modificar la celda con el contenido de un textbox llamado textbox1, ustedes le pueden poner el nombre que deseen al textbox
    xlibro.Range("B4").Value = txtCliente.Text;

    // 'Cargamos las celdas con los datos de la base de datos
    Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection Conexion;
    Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter Adaptador;

    Conexion = new Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection();
    Conexion.ConnectionString = "Data Source=abarrotes.db3;Version=3;";

    Conexion.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Adaptador = new Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from productos", Conexion);
    Adaptador.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow fila;
        int ValorInicial = 7; // 'Celda donde empezamos a insertar los articulos
        double Total = 0;

        foreach (var fila in ds.Tables(0).Rows)
        {
            xlibro.Range("A" + ValorInicial).Value = fila("Descripcion");
            xlibro.Range("B" + ValorInicial).Value = fila("precio");
            xlibro.Range("C" + ValorInicial).Value = fila("Cantidad");
            xlibro.Range("D" + ValorInicial).Value = fila("cantidad") * fila("precio");
            Total = Total + (fila("cantidad") * fila("precio"));

            ValorInicial += 1;
        }

        xlibro.Range("D17").Value = Total;
    }

    Conexion.Close(); }
```